# Hover keyframe values green and red

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm kind of stuck in a keyframe. I have a table with values from a fetch (json) and i should add a hover when the values is less than 5 in red and starting from 5 in green. This is my code in javascript ->

how do i have to implement the keyframe with it in css or is it different that i think?

```
 // Html

 <div id="group3">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr class="info">
          <th></th>
          <th>February</th>
          <th>March</th>
          <th>April</th>
          <th>May</th>
          <th>June</th>
          <th>July</th>
          <th>August</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id='mytable'>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

 //CSS
Keyframe?


 //hover

 let cells = document.querySelectorAll("tbody");
 cells.forEach( el => el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
   if(el.textContent < 5){
     el.classList.add('underfive');
   } else if (el.textContent >=5){
     el.classList.add('abovefive');
   }
 }));

  // reset animationx
  cells.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
   if(el.textContent < 5){
     el.classList.remove('underfive');
   } else if (el.textContent >=5){
     el.classList.remove('abovefive');
   }
 }));
```

it should be like this ->

[this is the startpage, background is white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKAKW.png)

[this is the end result how it should be, uploaded from a json file in a table, red value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhuF6.png)

[this is the green value when it's 5 of higher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eevgy.png)

Comment: Instead of manipulating classes, why don't you just set the background directly based on the value?

Comment: @SpiritPony how than?

Comment: @AnthonydeBecker I think something like ```element.style.background = "red";```. Look up documentation on how to do it. Set the background and foreground colours to what you want based on the value.

Comment: Im not clear what animation you want. Do you want the color to gradually come up from white to red. And could you explain the images you have shown which seem to have some of the cells coloured in half opacity?

Comment: @AHaworth hi, well the  background color is white when you go over a cell, it's going to another color(red or green) -> depends on the value.

i will put an other image when it's start

Comment: It is not really clear to me how the code you show is related to keyframes. And why do you need to add, remove those classes when the mouse enters and leaves the cell. Why don't you add the classes `underfive` and `abovefive` directly when you add those elements, once? I mean the information whether they have more or less than five elements do not change with the mouse event.

Comment: @t.niese how should i write the code than? only in css ? i thought you had to write code in Javascirpt for this and in css?

Comment: The question remains - what are those paler colors and how is it that there is both green and red on the same image? Are you sure this has anything to do with hover rather than showing, in varying shades of red a green what the value underneath is?

Comment: @AHaworth that's why i was thinking about keyframes to use? but i'm not sure about it

i'am a nooby you know :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you say you want to show a different background color or styling in general than the default if the mouse is over the `td`.

So use `:hover` for that. You want to have a transition between those states so use `transition`.

You want to have a different color if it is above or below 5. So define what you want to have as default and add a class for the other case.

```js
let data = [1,4,2,8,12,2,5,7];

const tr = document.querySelector('tr');
data.forEach(elem => {
   let td = document.createElement('td');
   td.textContent = elem;

   td.classList.toggle('belowfive', elem < 5);

   tr.appendChild(td);
});
```

```css
td {
  transition: background-color 1s;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid hsl(0 0% 50%);
}

td:hover {
   background-color: green;
}

td.belowfive:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You could also use ` td.classList.toggle('belowfive', elem < 5);`, which I personally think is neater than an if statement :)

Comment: thank you ! how do i use this code on the data which is loaded from a json in javascirpt? because this one gives me a new row with data 

let data = [1,4,2,8,12,2,5,7];

Comment: @AnthonydeBecker well you in some way fill the `tbody` of your table with the data you loaded, so what is the issue to apply the class there? The question is about how to do the hover effect and not how to populate the table?